# Validate Magento form input

Tags: validation, magento

My validation code outputs a error message only if something is written into the field. How can I also return the error message when the input field is left empty?

```
['validate-firstname', 'Please enter your firstname', function (v) {
            return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) ||  /^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(v)
        }],
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's an input field then you would just add the class `required-entry` to it.

As you can see in `js/prototype/validation.js` where the validation is declared (it's all based on Andrew Tetlaw's work here -> https://github.com/atetlaw/Really-Easy-Field-Validation )

```
['required-firstname', 'Please enter your first name.', function(v) {
            return !Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v);
        }],
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I would like it to output 'Please enter your firstname' when the input field is left empty and when non-letters are entered.

Comment: Hi, I've altered what was there. In that case you'd add the code I've put in above in the validation.js file and add the class `required-firstname` to the input field.